# MySQL - Insert variable into column while using INFILE

Tags: java, mysql

I'm writing an application in Java where I need to insert text files into a MySQL table.  These files can be tens of gigabytes.  I've decided to use LOCAL INFILE to do this for performance reasons.  The problem I'm running into is that I need to also insert a value based on a variable at the same time.

Assume the following table.

```
foo_string | bar_int
```

Assume the following data

```
a
bb
cccc
```

I'm first getting an id of a value from another table and storing it in a local int.  Then I go to execute the following query to insert the values from myvalues.txt

```
statement.executeUpdate( "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myvalues.txt' INTO TABLE  mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'");
```

The above works as expected but I'd also like to insert a value into the second (bar_int) column at the same time.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I'd update the row in another statement before the push of infile. Is it the same value for each row or a different value based on some fields in the file?

Comment: Each files data set will contain the same value for bar_int which is unknown to me until I query for it from the other table

Comment: Possible - see the [manual example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-preprocessing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a column list and then a `SET` clause:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myvalues.txt'
     INTO TABLE mytable
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
     (foo_string)
     SET bar_int = 1;
```

This reads the one column from the file into the column `foo_string`.  It sets `bar_int` to a specific value.